# OpenMP: why some threads are not working in dynamic scheduling

Tags: c++, dynamic, openmp

I was writing a program where there is a loop. Since each iteration will take different times, I decided to use dynamic scheduling. But when I run, some of the threads don't work even a single iteration. What I know about dynamic scheduling is

> OpenMP assigns one iteration to each thread. When the thread finishes, it will be assigned the next iteration that hasn’t been executed yet.

Below is the code.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
double start_time = 0.0, end_time = 0.0, total_time = 0.0;
start_time = omp_get_wtime();
int n, m, threads, scheduling_type;
n = 12, m = 8, threads = 12;
int row = (n - m) * (m - 1);
int col = n;

vector<vector<bool>> starting_comb(row);
vector<vector<bool>> ending_comb(row);
vector<vector<bool>> all_comb;
set<vector<bool>> temp_comb[row];
//calculate start and end combinations
A1(n, m, row, col, starting_comb, ending_comb);
//calculate each combination
//omp_set_num_threads(threads);
long long unsigned int total_tasks_per_thread[threads] = { 0 };
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic, 1) num_threads(12)
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        temp_comb[i] = A2(starting_comb[i], ending_comb[i], n);
        total_tasks_per_thread[omp_get_thread_num()] += temp_comb[i].size();
    }
for (int tasks = 0; tasks < 12; tasks++) {
    cout << total_tasks_per_thread[tasks] << ",T"<<(tasks+1)<<",";
}
end_time = omp_get_wtime();
total_time = end_time - start_time;
cout<< total_time;
return 0;
```

}

Output is

> 52,T1,85,T2,64,T3,0,T4,0,T5,66,T6,54,T7,57,T8,55,T9,62,T10,0,T11,0,T12,0.0220001

And it is not always the same of course. But there is always some "0" in the output.
I can't find what is wrong with the code. Or am I wrongly knowing about dynamic scheduling?

Comment: What does `A2` do?

Comment: A2 is used to generate every combinations from starting_comb[i] to ending_comb[i].

Comment: Since it returns a `set<vector<bool>>` it looks like there's lots of memory allocation being done in it.  That could create a bottleneck, where multiple threads have stalled waiting for their turn to allocate memory.  This, in turn, can cause your loop to not be able to run on all 12 threads.

Comment: But my computer has 8GB of ram and that programs in less than a second. Why should somethings like that happens? Can I force not to happen like that?

Comment: @nanda I cannot reproduce this effect with A1 and A2 performing just a sleep using gcc 9. Can A2 return empty sets ? Can you provide the full code with A1 and A2 (a link if it is too big) or at least a minimal *working* example so we can reproduce your results.

Comment: A2 won't return empty set. There would be at least one combination. The full code is here. https://ideone.com/HU1KKq    It is not too long(around 170lines of code.) I have reduced as much as I can.

Comment: On 1000 runs, the problem occurred only 4 times on my 6 cores machine if I adapt the number of threads from 12 to 6. How many cores and hardware threads do you have on you machine?

Comment: Additionally, on my machine, the parallel loop takes only 100 us in average which is clearly too small to expect all threads to be created before any other ends (and too small to expect any parallel speed-up > 1.0). Also note that you are measuring A1 in the printed timing.

Comment: My machine has 4 cores, and total number of logical processors is 8. When I runs "std::thread::hardware_concurrency()", it is 8 also. That is why only 8 threads works concurrently. But still, if I use static instead of dynamic, the iterations are distributed equally on all 12 threads. How does I works?